# Resize image versus different sizes of image

Tags: image

I am wondering why some popular websites like facebook and twitter use multiple sizes of pictures for user avatar. The image were all the same except for their sizes.

The question is, which is better?
Let's say that I have picture.jpg which is 100x100 px then I need a copy of it which is 50x50 px

What should I used?
Creating two picture file on my directory picture_100x100.jpg and picture_50x50.jpg
or simply using one picture then resize it using css?

Comment: It's probably so they can choose which to display based on the physical size of the display device: mobile phone, tablet, computer screen etc. Downsizing a large image often gives a poorer result than having an image specifically created at that size.

Answer (score 1):

There are two plausible reasons to have multiple image URLs on the server:

1. Bandwidth - particularly important for mobile devices using 2G or similar slow networks, which is still an issue today. You want to send the absolute minimum amount of data, and large images can be a bandwidth hog, even when using a lossy compression scheme such as JPEG.
2. The large version of the image may be based on a "master" uploaded image which is even larger. Double-downsizing may introduce imperfections relative to downsizing once from the master image.